# A good solution for commenting on PDFs or ODTs

Tags: google-drive, adobe-reader, cloud, comments

I am currently writing a paper in LibreOffice which needs to be reviewed and commented on by multiple people. I wanted a way that everybody could simultaneously view and comment on the document. I also wanted a way to set the status of comments in a more sophisticated way than simply setting them to "resolved". Ideally we could all be notified when new comments are made, and/or at least sort comments by date to quickly see which new ones need to be addressed. A (free) solution that meets all these requirements and works correctly is eluding me. Converting to PDF and using the options below seems like the best I can come up with, but it is not enough.

Here is what I have tried:

#### Adobe Reader

Adobe Reader allows comments to be set as Accepted, Rejected, Completed or Cancelled. Which is great, and then later you can filter the comments by their status, but unfortunately if you have a whole discussion under one comment and then want to mark the comment as Accepted (meaning I will do what we have agreed to here), you will need to set **every** sub-comment to Accepted as well, otherwise if you filter by comments with a status of None, you will still see those all those comment threads where you set only the first or last comment to Accepted. Adobe Reader on it's own does not give simultaneous access to other viewers to the document.

#### Google Drive

Google Drive does allow multiple simultaneous readers and commenters, which is wonderful. And we can get automatic notifications about new comments. However, in my experience, clicking on comment notification links in your email on a computer will load the document in a browser tab, but it will not go to the correct location of the comment, which is not very helpful. You can read the comment in the email, but you can't see the context of what they were talking about. Google Drive lets you click on a comment and get a link to it, but the link doesn't actually work. It opens the document and then scrolls to a random location. The email links DO work on my Android phone, when it opens in the Drive App. So that is nice, but it is not so nice to respond to a lot of comments by phone. Google Drive does not allow any sorting or filtering of comments and the only comment status it understands is its own system of "Resolved" or not. It is incompatible with the Adobe comment statuses and instead converts them all to comments themselves, saying "Accepted set by Moss" once for every sub-comment that you marked as Accepted!

The best thing I can think of right now is to tell the reviewers that they can't comment in Google Drive directly. They have to download the file, send the rest of us an email saying they are currently commenting, do their thing in Adobe, and then re-upload the file, and "check out" by email again. In my experience, opening the PDF file from a Google Drive sync folder directly causes havoc. Adobe Reader becomes extremely slow and displays duplicates of comments.

---

Another possible solution is to use Adobe Acrobat Pro DC which allows online commenting and I assume it must work with all the normal Adobe Reader commenting features. But $13 USD a month is a bit much, considering that I am working on this paper slowly and needing to do comments every other month or so for maybe two weeks, but there is no consistent schedule. I might need to handle comments at any time.

Well, this question is probably so long now that nobody will answer it. But at least I got to rant for awhile. If someone does actually read this whole thing and have any experience with this kind of problem, please let me know if you have a better solution.

Comment: If the links to comments worked properly then I could possibly get by without the variety of comment statuses and just make a todo list of links to comments that I have "accepted". Then I could set comments to Resolved when I am really done with them. And any other statuses like "Rejected" could be done by just saying "I disagree" in a sub-comment. Unfortunately Google Drive doesn't allow searching of comments or any formatting like bold or italics.

Comment: Oh, turns out Acrobat DC is not even available in the country where I am working.

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft Word? It also has good commenting capability and you can use the online version for free. I don't say that's the solution as I don't use commenting so intensively, but definitely worth a try.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I am commited to LibreOffice at this point. I just checked out Word online and the commenting is still super basic, like LibreOffice. And when I click on the comments it doesn't even go to the corresponding place in the document!